# extend rich:select / h:select to have multiple selections

Tags: jsf-2

Is it possible to extend rich:select or h:selectOneMenu to enable multiple selection? I am looking for a jsf component which looks like the [jQuery Chosen plugin](http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-chosen). 
The component should let me select multiple options from the drop down.
Please note that I can not use h:selectManyMenu or list box because of the specific requirement.

Note: just saw the tags field below the description box while posting a question. I am looking exactly for the same functionality, except that I want a JSF component, not a js plugin.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use that jQuery Chosen plugin and do something like this:

- use jQuery to apply it to your select
- use jQuery to get the selected data
- pass the data to the backing bean via a hidden input field

There may be 'pure JSF' ways but it looks like more work. If you find something interesting let me know.

Comment: The styles for chosen are not applied for rich:select. That was the reason I could not go for it.

Comment: I implemented this with a couple of divs and utilizing the existing `rich:select`. This works just like the jQuery plug in.